# Html.Action() results in "No route in the route table matches the supplied values"

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-routing, umbraco6

This issue has been discussed many times, but I haven't found a resolution for my particular case.

In one of my Umbraco (6) views I am calling a controller method by using

```
@Html.Action("Index", "CountryListing");
```

This results in the "no route in the route table" exception.

I have been fiddling around with the RegisterRoutes method to no avail. I wonder if it is even used as the site still functions when I empty the RegisterRoutes method. This is what it looks like now:

```
public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
        {
            routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "Default",
                url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
                defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
            );
        }
```

I have also tried adding an empty "area" to the call like this

```
@Html.Action("Index", "CountryListing", new {area: String.Empty});
```

I am using @Html.Action statements in other places and they DO work, so I do understand why some of them work and others don't, but the main problem now is getting my country listing action to work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can solve this by doing the following

1. Make sure your Controller is extending Umbraco's SurfaceController
2. Name it YourName*SurfaceController*
3. Add the [PluginController("CLC")] 'annotation' (I am from Java) to your controller. CLC stands for CountryListController. You can make up your own name of course.
4. Add the PluginController name (CLC) to the Html.Action call as a "Area" parameter.

My controller:

```
[PluginController("CLC")]
public class CountryListingSurfaceController : SurfaceController
{
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
       var listing = new CountryListingModel();

       // Do stuff here to fill the CountryListingModel

       return PartialView("CountryListing", listing);
    }
}
```

My partial view (CountryListing.cshtml):

```
@inherits UmbracoViewPage<PatentVista.Models.CountryListingModel>

@foreach (var country in Model.Countries)
{
    <span>More razor code here</span>  
}
```

The Action call:

```
@Html.Action("Index", "CountryListingSurface", new {Area= "CLC"})
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use null instead of using String.empty

```
@Html.Action("Index", "CountryListing",null);
```

if you are using area, you have to override RegisterRoutes for every area

```
public override string AreaName
    {
        get
        {
            return "CountryListing";
        }
    }

    public override void RegisterArea(AreaRegistrationContext context)
    {
        context.MapRoute(
            "CountryListing_default",
            "CountryListing/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            new { action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );
    }
```

and i  recommend you take a look at the same problem:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/11970111/2543986

Comment: User2543... thanks for your reply. Unfortunately adding null didn't do the trick and I didn't understand your other solution. I have however found a solution in the meantime. I think this problem has to do with Umbraco... (although it is also a generic MVC problem)..